# What is the recommended way to set the size of a dialog window in Java

Tags: java, jdialog

I have a lengthy Java class

```
public class EditDialog extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ... {
    private JButton editDialog;
    // lots of code

    public EditDialog (String setting){
        this.setting = setting;
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        // lots of code
    }
}
```

This dialog can be resized but the default dimensions are too small. I want to set larger size by default while keeping the scaling ability. How can I do this? It seems that `getPreferredSize` and `setPreferredSize` might be useful, but I can't find an example how to use these functions.

Comment: You haven't actually shown a [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), so it's hard to say.  But in general you call `setSize()` on the top level frame/dialog before making it visible.

Comment: That answers my question. setSize() was burried three classes away. Changing the values changed the dimensions of the window. Can you move your comment to answer section, so I can mark it as "solved"? thanks again.

Comment: There you go.  Yes, it's buried and there's tons of methods on those Swing classes.  It'll be easier to remember the important methods as you get more experience.  You know about `pack()`, right?

Comment: I have heard about pack() in combination with "it might not work with setSize()", but I will read about it since you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Use `pack()` first, then call `setSize()`.  I like to make sure the layout is properly set up first before I call `setSize()`.  It might not be needed but I haven't seen any trouble doing it this way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you call [setSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize-int-int-) on the top level frame/dialog before making it visible.

C.f. [Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)